# Error when creating first application on RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, osx-mavericks

I am following instructions from the book "Agile Web Development with Rails". I have downloaded rails, ruby, sqlite3 onto my MacBookPro, which is running Mavericks.

I am now trying to create a new application for the first time, using the command

```
rails new demo
```

but receive the following error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for rb_integer_pack()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling backup.c
compiling database.c
database.c:300:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling exception.c
compiling sqlite3.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [sqlite3_native.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/pk/2wfx1lm90gzb2mnzsgkntf480000gp/T/bundler20140702-7691-10in5mk/sqlite3-1.3.9/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/pk/2wfx1lm90gzb2mnzsgkntf480000gp/T/bundler20140702-7691-10in5mk/sqlite3-1.3.9/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:357:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:164:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I have researched this topic, and found different suggestions on different forums, but each time, I still get the same error. Any advice greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are failed with the sqlite3 gem installation. Following are the instructions i used to setup a new ruby environment in mac.

1. Install homebrew. with homebrew you can install sqlite3 or mysql with just a command like
   brew install sqlite3
2. Install rvm
3. Install ruby and rails with rvm

Comment: nickcen, Thank you. I think I already have homebrew installed, because a command brew --version, returns 0.9.5. Also, I think I already have sqlite3 installed, because a command sqlite3 --version returns 3.8.4.3. I think I have ruby install because a command ruby --version, returns ruby 2.0.0p247.